# Import 3D models from AC3D in OpenGL-ES on iOS

Tags: opengl-es, ios5, xcode4.2, 3d

Lately i have got a task to import a 3D model which is created in AC3D into my OpenGL-ES application. Unfortunately im quite lost where to look and what to choose.

The 3D model consist of 6 objects, which should be individually controlled.

I have been looking at different type of readers, such as Wavefront etc. but i dont seem to get the proper implementation into my current project.

Anybody you can point me a little in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Feel free to have a look here https://github.com/epatel/ac3dreader

and this page about using it http://www.memention.com/ac3dreader/usage/

Comment: Thanks for your reply epatel. I have in fact already contacted you concerning something specific, so it was a interesting coinsidense that you replied here aswell. :-)